# Objc computed property vs method

Tags: objective-c

I just saw this in the Apple source:

```
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *uppercaseString;
```

So to uppercase a string one would do

```
@"sdfks".uppercaseString;
```

Is there any advantage doing it this way and not just a method

```
- (NSString *) uppercaseString;
```

I am positive it is the same, but I really want to know why would you use the readonly variant instead of method or other way around.

Comment: Yes, it's the same, it's just a much more convenient way of declaring the getter and setter and the implementation can be automatically generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way or the other, you are using a method.

Objective-C properties boil down to a method (or a pair of methods for settable properties) that you can call using two alternative kinds of syntax - the dot syntax

```
@"sdfks".uppercaseString
```

and the regular method call syntax

```
[@"sdfks" uppercaseString]
```

Dot syntax becomes more convenient when you need to access properties of objects produced by other method calls:

```
person.address.city.uppercaseString
```

syntax has less punctuation than

```
[[[person address] city] uppercaseString]
```

and for that reason may be more visually appealing to some programmers.